# How deep should be the copy (assignment) of a type-erased map

Tags: c++, dictionary, copy, type-erasure

I am writing a library in C++ for which I implemented a map wrapper with type erasure.  The wrapper is structured as in this wonderful article: http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/articles/18756/.

TLDR:

```
template<typename K, typename V>
class AnyMap
{
    class MapConcept
    {
    public:
        // Lots of pure virtual methods...
        // These mimic the intersection of STL and Boost maps' interfaces
        // Example:
        virtual size_type size() = 0;
    };

    template<typename ActualMapType>
    class MapModel : MapConcept
    {
        ActualMapType m;
    public:
        // Implementations of the parent's virtual methods...
        // These basically just call the same method on member m.
        // Example:
        size_type size()  { return m.size(); }
    };

    MapConcept* mapConcept;

public:
    // Again, the STL and Boost maps' interface methods
    // Example:
    size_type size()  { return mapConcept->size(); }
};
```

I'm not sure whether I will expose this map as part of the finished library or tuck it away as a helper class, but either way I'm wondering what do with the assignment operator.

Currently, I have something like this:

```
AnyMap& AnyMap::operator=(const AnyMap& other) {
    delete mapConcept;
    mapConcept = other.mapConcept->clone();
    return *this;
}
```

This means that if I create two maps with say an STL's map and a Boost's unordered_map and then assign one to the other, both will now have the same map type underlying them.

```
std::map<string, int> stlMap;
boost::unordered_map<string, int> boostMap;
// insert some stuff into maps
AnyMap<string, int> stlAnyMap( stlMap );
AnyMap<string, int> boostAnyMap( boostMap );

stlAnyMap = boostAnyMap;
// now stlAnyMap has a copy of boostMap
```

So, this makes some sense because the contents of the map assigned to are what's expected.  However, I suspect that usually the map types will differ by one of the type arguments with default values (such as Hash in Boost::unordered_map).  So, maybe it should retain the underlying map type. I think, this can be done with something like the following:

```
AnyMap& AnyMap::operator=(const AnyMap& other) {
    mapConcept->clear();
    mapConcept->insert( other.mapConcept->begin(), other.mapConcept->end() );
    return *this;
}
```

This should work because of the templated insert method:

```
template <class InputIterator>
  void insert (InputIterator first, InputIterator last);
```

By the way, if anyone is wondering how I dealt with the iterators: I used Thomas Becker's any_iterator - http://thbecker.net/free_software_utilities/type_erasure_for_cpp_iterators/any_iterator.html.

So, what do you guys think?  I'm leaning toward the latter approach, but I'd like to hear any arguments for either side.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: Here is the first argument against (perhaps, you could tell me how important this is): the contents of one map type might now map one-to-one to another map if one predicate distinguishes two keys in the map while the other considers them the same.

Comment: The article is very misguided. There's no type erasure in C++. He just hides (does not erase) different types behind a uniform interface. This is usually called an "adapter". Regarding your question: `x` and `y` are objects of the same type, so after `x=y` they should be identical, period. Anything else is plainly broken.

Answer (score 1):

Do you want the map wrapper to have value semantics or not?  That will determine how deep the copy has to be.  In any case, the implementation of `other.mapConcept->clone()` will be polymorphic (this is, after all, the essence of the C++ type erasure technique) and result in a dispatch to a call in the MapModel subclass that looks like this

```
virtual MapModel *clone() { return new MapModel(m); } // covariant return type
```

So everything boils down to what ActualMapType's copy constructor does (since the member variable `m` will be a copy.)

Since the technique was invented to get value semantics, I think retaining that feature is consistent with the principle of Least Surprise.  Moreover, the point is to have a fixed *interface*.  The implementation (STL or boost or whatever) is irrelevant by design, so there is little point in trying to retain the implementation in any particular object instance.

Incidentally your implementation of operator= for the "standard" case is not exception safe. The copy-and-swap idiom (perhaps with a custom swap() method) works better

```
AnyMap( AnyMap const& other )
: mapConcept( other.mapConcept ? other.mapConcept->clone() : 0)
{}

AnyMap& operator= ( AnyMap rhs ) // note temporary: invokes copy constructor
{ std::swap( mapConcept, rhs.mapConcept ) ; return *this; }
```

Comment: Could you elaborate?
First, did you mean: virtual MapConcept *clone() { return new MapModel(m); }
Second, I'm going to construct some default MapModel so that I don't have to worry about mapConcept==NULL here and in every other method of AnyMap.
Third, about the temporary... am I missing something or are you?  If I understand right, this will swap the two objects rather than making *this equal to rhs.  Should that be operator=(AnyMap && rhs)?

Comment: MapConcept will declare a pure `virtual MapConcept* clone() = 0;`.  The implementation in the MapModel subclass will be `virtual MapModel* clone() { /* etc. */ )`.  this works because of [covariant return types](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariant_return_type).  As for the [copy-and-swap idiom](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Copy-and-swap), I need to edit my reply to make the process clearer.  It wasn't right as originally written. Sorry about that.

Comment: BTW, the problem with my original version was that the call `swap(rhs)` (instead of std::swap as it is now) also needed a `AnyMap::swap( AnyMap& )` member method in which the `mapConcept` members would be swapped.

Comment: Thanks.  Yeah, I took a look at the copy-and-swap and that cleared things up.  But then, does there need to be a AnyMap& operator=(AnyMap rhs) as well as AnyMap& operator=(const AnyMap & rhs)?

Comment: The second isn't needed at all: the first takes care of everything.

Comment: Ah, got it... just didn't read the article carefully enough.  Thanks.

Comment: Herb Sutter's book "Exceptional C++" covers this in excellent detail.